# How to add attribute/parameters to the url in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages dynamically?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

If the user change or enter the url manually ,I want to add attribute "culture" to the url .

For example the user wants to go to the "post" page and change the url to the "https://localhost:4432/post"  manually,then I want to add attribute  "?culture=" to the url,I write this code in "post.cshtml.cs" class but it doesn't work :

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{
    string culture = "fa";

    if (Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("_culture"))
        culture = Request.Cookies["_culture"].ToString();

    Response.Redirect("/post?culture=" + culture);

    return Page();
}
```

The result is here:

[image: The result is here:]

> This page isn't working:
> localhost redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies.
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: How do you know the user did it manually?

Comment: By the way, the error is clear: you made a loop.

Comment: Some Users Enter manually.

Comment: And how did you can know wich ones are manually and wich ones doesn't?  Also you are checking "cookies" (¿?) instead or parameters. That's why you made a loop. You are redirecting to the same action over and over

Comment: I think this one is a [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/) you should not check (and can't) if a url is typed or not

Comment: What should I do for Solve the problem of falling into the loop?@LeandroBardelli

Comment: You should check the "culture" parameter but you wont never solve the original problem of someone writing the url

Comment: As @LeandroBardelli stated you have an infinite loop going. You need to do another `if` statement in the method that clicks for the URI fragment. If the ?culture= is in the URL then no redirect is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break out of the infinite loop of the redirect. `If` the requested URL does not have the query tag for culture then add it with the redirect and return the page. `Else` just return the page.

```
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {

        string culture = Request.Query["culture"];

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {

            culture = "fa";

            if (Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("_culture"))
                culture = Request.Cookies["_culture"].ToString();

            Response.Redirect("/post?culture=" + culture);
        }

        return Page();
    }
```